# Can I do an atomic MERGE in Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, concurrency, merge, weblogic

I have a couple instances of a J2EE app running in a single WebLogic cluster.

At some point, these apps do a MERGE to insert or update a record into the back-end Oracle database. The MERGE checks to see if a row with a specified primary key is there or not. If it's there, update. If not, insert.

Now suppose two app instances want to insert or update a row with primary key = 100. Suppose the row doesn't exist. During the "check" stage of merge, they both see that the rows not there, so both of them attempt to insert. Then I get a unique key constraint violation.

My question is this: Is there an atomic MERGE in Oracle? I'm looking for something that has a similar effect to `INSERT ... FOR UPDATE` in PL/SQL except that I can only execute SQL from my apps.

EDIT: I was unclear. I AM using the MERGE statement while this error still occurs. The thing is, only the "modifying" part is atomic, not the whole merge.

Comment: The merge is atomic. It either works or fails as a complete unit of work. What you are seeing is a result of Oracle's implementation of multiversion consistancy. Sounds like you are looking for something to seralize the multiple merges? You might try using Oracle's seralizable transactions, but that will probably just change the error from unique key constraint to a can not serialize the transaction error.

Comment: My database/multi-thread vocab might be wrong. My understanding is the "work or fail as a complete unit of work" is called transactional. By atomic, I meant no merge can happen while another merge is processing. About serializing merges, I'll have to read about that. Thanks.

Comment: @Russell, atomicity is just one property of a transaction. And it does mean succeed or fail as a unit. For exapmle see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID and http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/transact.htm#sthref1298.

Comment: Where is the primary key coming from that you can have new duplicates?

Comment: Ah, good recap for ACID. Thanks. I haven't heard that a long while ago since I last worked with databases. The primary key comes from an external source that I have no control over.

Comment: Do the statements in both sessions fail, or does one fail and the other is successful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MERGE statement in the second session can not "see" the insert that the first session did until that session commits. If you reduce the size of the transactions the probability that this will occur will be reduced.

Or, can you sort or partition your data so that all records of a given primary key will be given to the same session. A simple function like "primary key mod N" should distribute evenly to N sessions.

btw, if two records have the same primary key, the second will overwrite the first. Sounds a little odd.

Comment: This does not answer the question. And the workaround will not work if you want to synchronize two separate applications having only the db as a common element.

Answer (score 15):

This is not a problem with MERGE as such.  Rather the issue lies in your application.  Consider this stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure upsert_t23 
    ( p_id in t23.id%type
      , p_name in t23.name%type )
is
    cursor c is
        select null 
        from t23
        where id = p_id;
    dummy varchar2(1);
begin
    open c;
    fetch c into dummy;
    if c%notfound then
        insert into t23 
            values (p_id, p_name);
    else
        update t23
             set name = p_name
             where id = p_id;
    end if;
 end;
```

So, this is the PL/SQL equivalent of a MERGE on T23.  What happens if two sessions call it simultaneously?

```
SSN1>  exec upsert_t23(100, 'FOX IN SOCKS')

SSN2>  exec upsert_t23(100, 'MR KNOX')
```

SSN1 gets there first, finds no matching record and inserts a record.   SSN2 gets there second but before SSN1 commits, finds no record, inserts a record *and hangs* because SSN1 has a lock on the unique index node for 100.  When SSN1 commits SSN2 will hurl a DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX violation.

The MERGE statement works in exactly the same way.  Both sessions will check `on (t23.id = 100)`, not find it and go down the INSERT branch.  The first session will succeed and the second will hurl ORA-00001.

One way to handle this is to introduce pessimistic locking.  At the start of the UPSERT_T23 procedure we lock the table:

```
...
lock table t23 in row shared mode nowait;
open c;
...
```

Now, SSN1 arrives, grabs the lock and proceeds as before.  When SSN2 arrives it can't get the lock, so it fails immediately.  Which is frustrating for the second user but at least they are not hanging, plus they know someone else is working on the same record.

There is no syntax for INSERT which is equivalent to SELECT ... FOR UPDATE, because there is nothing to select.  And so there is no such syntax for MERGE either.  What you need to do is include the LOCK TABLE statement in the program unit which issues the MERGE.  Whether this is possible for you depends on the framework you're using.

Comment: Thanks, that was perfect articulation of what I was trying to explain in my question. About how you would handle the problem, isn't the lock thing part of PL/SQL? I'm looking for a workaround/solution using Oracle's SQL that can be called from my app. I wasn't really looking for an INSERT which is equivalent to SELECT ... FOR UPDATE (although the way I stated it might have led you to think that way). I was just finding if there were any ways to lock the row being merged through a MERGE statement (hence the question's title). By all means, thanks for the thorough answer and knowledge :)

Comment: Locking a table in Row Share (not Row Shared) accomplishes almost nothing. It will prevent another session from getting an Exclusive table lock. It will not prevent another session from updating/inserting/deleting.  btw, the Row Share lock is automatically acquired when you issue a "select .. for update" statement. The "Share Row Exclusive" mode will prevent other sessions from changing the table and you can't acquire it if another session has uncommitted changes. This is almost as restictive as an Exclusive Lock. Using it will prevent all concurrent updates - like a "single user" system.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and it's called.... [MERGE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm)

**EDIT**: The only way to get this water tight is to insert, catch the dup_val_on_index exception and handle it appropriately (update, or insert other record perhaps). This can easily be done with PL/SQL, but you can't use that.

You're also looking for workarounds. Can you catch the dup_val_on_index in Java and issue an extra UPDATE again?

In pseudo-code:

```
try {
  // MERGE
}
catch (dup_val_on_index) {
  // UPDATE
}
```

Comment: OK, I'll look into it some more after my weekend!

Comment: Are you able to use PL/SQL? First thing that I found suggests that an insert with exception handling (when dup_val_on_index then update) is the only way to get this water tight.

Comment: As stated in the question, no I can't. I was thinking of that option as well.

Comment: When using JPA, reaching the catch part in Java means the transaction is already marked for rollback, no chance to commit the update then!

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk - what kind of exception is on catch? SQLException?

Comment: @powerMock I think so, but Java is not really my cup of tea, sorry.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk, I tested it. It is not an SQLException, because it's not compulsory to catch it. It is a RuntimeException.

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised that MERGE would behave the way you describe, but I haven't used it sufficiently to say whether it should or not.

In any case, you might have the transactions that wish to execute the merge set their isolation level to SERIALIZABLE.  I think that may solve your issue.