# UPDATE does not lock table if no rows match, race condition

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions, locking

I want to increment and return a counter from a database table.

The java code is as follows:

```
String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE mytable SET col3 = col3 + 1 WHERE colpk1 = ? AND colpk2 = ?";
Query queryUpdate = manager.createNativeQuery(sqlUpdate);
queryUpdate.setParameter(1, ...);
queryUpdate.setParameter(2, ...);

int num = queryUpdate.executeUpdate();

if (num == 0) {
    long count = 1;
    String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO mytable (colpk1, colpk2, col3) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    Query queryInsert = manager.createNativeQuery(sqlInsert);
    queryInsert.setParameter(1, ...);
    queryInsert.setParameter(2, ...);
    queryInsert.setParameter(3, count);
    queryInsert.executeUpdate();

    return count;
} else {
    String sqlSelect = "SELECT col3 FROM mytable WHERE colpk1 = ? AND colpk2 = ?";
    Query querySelect = manager.createNativeQuery(sqlSelect);
    querySelect.setParameter(1, ...);
    querySelect.setParameter(2, ...);

    Object result = querySelect.getSingleResult();

    return Long.parseLong(result.toString());
}
```

This works well also concurrently used (creates a lock) in case there is already a row with the given primary key. However, in case that row does not exist yet (num == 0), the UPDATE does not lock, and a concurrent access can happen in between the two queries, then leading to a Unique Constraint validation when executing the INSERT as the new row was already created in the meantime.

What's the best way to solve this problem? Would it be better to use a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` first and then depending on the result doing an UPDATE or INSERT?

Comment: `SELECT FOR UPDATE` does also not block if there are no rows satisfying the condiiton.

Comment: As the `Merge` solution suggested below did not work, I tried catching the exception and re-doing the update, once an exception happened, I cannot get the transaction to commit any more within the app server (setRollbackOnly).

Comment: This question shows why Merge is not a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226830/can-i-do-an-atomic-merge-in-oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Merge can throw the Unique Constraint exception in concurrent execution, the best solution was to catch the exception when executing the insert, then the row must be there already, and continue with the update then.

Getting this transaction to commit in case of container managed transactions was the next problem, as the exception lead to `isRollBackOnly == true`. The way that worked was to use a new bean call for trying the insert within a new transaction, see [Commit transaction after exception - undo setRollbackOnly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088574/commit-transaction-after-exception-undo-setrollbackonly)

Answer (score 1):

The `MERGE` statement will avoid the split statements.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)

Alternatively, you could always trap the Unique constraint exception for the rare cases when the condition occurs, and retry.

Comment: [Here is a link to the Oracle 11G documentation on Merge, if it helps.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/statements_9016.htm)

Comment: Thank you. If I use a SELECT immediately after the MERGE statement to retrieve the currently incremented counter value, am I guaranteed then to retrieve the one I increased, and not a higher value as it might have been increased in the meantime by a parallel MERGE? I.e. does MERGE lock?

Comment: @stracktracer Have a look at the `RETURNING` clause. Does it work with `MERGE` - I don't know!

Comment: The only syntax I found working (as source and target are equal is) is by using DUAL:
`MERGE INTO myTable m USING (SELECT 1 FROM dual ) n  ON (m.colpk1 = ... AND m.colplk2 = ...) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET o.col3 = o.col3 + 1 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (colpk1, colpk2, col3) VALUES (...,...,1);`

Comment: Interestingly, with this single merge statement I also receive a Unique Constraint violation in concurrent access situations!

Comment: `RETURNING` with Merge is not supported by Oracle.

Comment: MERGE is NOT thread-safe.  According to this: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx  MERGE will implicitly take out an update lock, but releases it before performing an insert, which creates a race condition that could result in primary key violations as stracktracer mentions.  You have to add a HOLDLOCK to the statement to ensure the locks are kept until after the update completes.  IMO, this is an epic failure of the MERGE statement, because it's misleading as a single statement which is not atomic.