# Commit transaction after exception - undo setRollbackOnly

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb-3.0, eclipselink

Within my method with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` there can sometimes happen a `org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException` due to an `SQLException`. I catch this exception and handle the situation by another database query. However, this query does not get through, as due to the exception, setRollbackOnly is automatically set and I am unable to commit the transaction any more at this point.

In Java SE I'd do an explicit

```
manager.getTransaction().rollback();
manager.getTransaction().begin();
```

but within the application server this is not working of course.

Can I somehow get my database changes to commit in this situation?

Comment: Can you get status of transaction after it is finished? Or catch the exception out of transaction and execute required logic in new transaction?

Comment: I could return a return value that indicates the caller to re-execute the method he just executed. However, I want it to be transparent to the caller.

Comment: I mean in your method calling that other method..

Comment: Call a method on another bean annotated with REQUIRES_NEW ...

Comment: Yes this could work - strangely, I get an SQLException `XAER_PROTO : Routine was invoked in an inproper context` now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint given in esej's comment was the solution:
"Call a method on another bean annotated with REQUIRES_NEW."

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will 'Routine was invoked etc..' error when you attempt to start a new global transaction while the previous transaction was neither committed nor rollbacked.

In order to fix this, you should do the following:

When you catch the first exception, don't leave it up to the container to flag the transaction as 'rollback'. You have to manually flag the transaction as rollback.